# Matplotlib - logarithmic scale, but require non-logarithmic labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I stop the y-axis displaying a logarithmic notation label on the y-axis?

I'm happy with the logarithmic scale, but want to display the absolute values, e.g. [500, 1500, 4500, 11000, 110000] on the Y-axis. I don't want to explicitly label each tick as the labels may change in the future (I've tried out the different formatters but haven't successfully gotten them to work). Sample code below.

Thanks,

-collern2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([500, 1500, 4500, 11000, 110000])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_yscale('log')

plt.plot(b, a)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You may want to ask specific questions like this on matplotlib's user mailing list.

Comment: What is the user mailing list?

Comment: I'm confused as I'm not sure what a "logarithmic notation label" is.  Do you want to change the format of the labels (from 10^3 to 1000) or do you want to add ticks (or replace the current ticks by ticks) at the positions in a?

Comment: The former - change the format of the labels (from 10^3 to 1000)

Comment: 10^3 is not logarithmic notation, it is scientific notation.

Answer (score 33):

If I understand correctly,

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

any of

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: str(int(round(x)))))
```

should work.  '%d' will have problems if the tick labels locations wind up being at places like 4.99, but you get the idea.

Note that you may need to do the same with the minor formatter, `set_minor_formatter`, depending on the limits of the axes.

Comment: +1 for also giving an example based on a `lambda`. This pretty much opens the door for every possible value-to-string mapping. Imho this answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Use ticker.FormatStrFormatter

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker

a = np.array([500, 1500, 4500, 11000, 110000])
b = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_yscale('symlog')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter("%d"))

plt.plot(b, a)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```