# Python, matplotlib: how to set tick label values to their logarithmic values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm

I have some data that I plot on a semi-log plot (log-lin style, with a logarithmic scale on the y-axis).  Is there a way to change the y-axis tick labels from their actual values to their logarithmic values?

As an example, consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
def f(x):
    return 10**(x-1)

plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.yscale(u'log')

plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot:
[image]

(Sorry it is kind of big, I do not know how to make it smaller, feel free to edit to help out with that).

In this plot the tick labels are shown as 10^0, 10^1, 10^2, etc.; however I would like them to display as their logarithmic values: 0, 1, 2, etc.

I realize I could go back and change `plt.plot(x,f(x))` to `plt.plot(x,np.log10(f(x)))` and then make the y-axis linear again instead of logarithmic but I want to know if there is anyway matplotlib can just change the y-axis tick values themselves without me having to put `np.log10()` in all my `plt.plot()`'s.  My reason for this is two-fold: I have many `plt.plot()` lines in my code and would rather not go back and have to change it for all of them, and then I wouldn't have logarithmically spaced minor ticks (although I'm sure there's some way to change that even with a linear axis).

**EDIT:**  I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431248/matplotlib-logarithmic-scale-but-require-non-logarithmic-labels) which has some similarities to mine but is not the same.  The person in that question wants to change the tick labels from scientific form to "normal" decimal form.  I want to change my tick labels from scientific form to the logarithmic (base 10) value of the number.  I am sure the answer will be similar to the one I linked but it is not obvious to me how to do it.  In fact, I looked at that question before posting mine but still decided to post mine because I did not know how to apply it to my problem.  Perhaps to experienced programmers it is obvious how to apply the methods of the question I linked to my situation but it isn't obvious to me so please step me through it.

If you could show me a code sample (by copying my code sample and putting in the necessary lines) how this works I would much appreciate it.

Comment: use a formatter http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html

Comment: not sure the date formatter is the best target link... @PaulH

Comment: Use a [log scale](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html). You should try looking at the [gallery pages](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and searching for what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom formatter, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import numpy as np
import math

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

def f(x):
    return 10**(x-1)

plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.yscale(u'log')

#SET CUSTORM TICK FORMATTING
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x,y: '{}'.format(math.log(x, 10))))

plt.show()
```