# Matplotlib:non logarithmic labels when plotting logarithm

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm

I am plotting a histogram, taking the logarithm of the quantity before plotting, (instead of choosing a logarithmic scale for my plot) and in the tick labels on the x axis I obviously get the logarithm. 
I would like labels to show the scientific notation instead: in other words I would like 10^3 instead of 3, for example.

Is there any way to do that? I saw other questions, like [Matplotlib - logarithmic scale, but require non-logarithmic labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431248/matplotlib-logarithmic-scale-but-require-non-logarithmic-labels), but this is not the same thing, I didn' use `ax.set_xscale('log')`.
Here is a line of my code:

```
ax[0, 0].hist(np.log10(bh_100[:, 0]),bins=15, ls='dashed', color= 'b',   log=True, label = 'Bh-bh')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use [`set_xticklabels`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels) to set the labels as you require them

For example, you can do:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['10^{%d}'%i for i in range(5)])
```

or LaTeX-style:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['$10^{%d}$'%i for i in range(5)])
```

Comment: I had thought of that, but it would be complicated, it is it is a multi-subplot figure..

Comment: I don't know a built-in way to do what you want. What about writing your own function that loops over all subplots and changes the labels?