# How to have customized ticks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scientific-notation

I made a log scale graph below.

How to show the regular ticks without scientific notation?

How to customize ticks with different format combined?

```
plt.plot(np.arange(1000))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(1,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you said that you've tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431248/matplotlib-logarithmic-scale-but-require-non-logarithmic-labels), and they didn't work, I suspect it is because you called `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter` *before* setting the `scale` to `log`. If you do that, it resets the x and y axes when you say `plt.xscale('log')` and `plt.yscale('log')`.

If you call it after, it works:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

plt.plot(np.arange(1000))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Must I use `ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)` ? Can I use `plt` directly' ?

Comment: You can use `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())` and `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())` if you want

Comment: Thanks. what's the purpose to use `fig = plt.figure()` and `ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)` ? To make the code neat, why not just use `plt` ?

Comment: It's just a way to explicitly create an axes object, sometimes it can be easier to refer to actual axes.

Comment: Thanks. I re-editted the question and added `plt.ylim(1,10)`, now it doesn't work again. BTW, the new ticks have a decimal point, how can I get rid of it.