# How to show only y axis values with scalar format?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a semilogy matplotlib plot, I would like to have only y axis ticks values with decimal notation (like: 0.4, 10 etc.) but no scientific values (like 4e-1, 1e2 etc.).

The solution shown in [Matplotlib log scale tick label number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213196/10698244)  and also depicted below, does not work properly, when the axis tick values are not tens potency values:

[image: y axis tick labels have exponential description]

How do I have to change the code that the y axis tick labels descriptions are [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, and 0.04]?

Or is there nowadays a matplotlib function that does this automatically?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [0.04, 0.007]})

import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.semilogy(df.set_index('a').b, 'o', markersize=2)


def myLogFormat(y, pos):
    # Find the number of decimal places required
    decimalplaces = int(np.maximum(-np.log10(y), 0))  # =0 for numbers >=1
    # Insert that number into a format string
    formatstring = '{{:.{:1d}f}}'.format(decimalplaces)
    # Return the formatted tick label
    return formatstring.format(y)


ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(myLogFormat))
# ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:g}'.format(y)))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431725/4932316)

```
from matplotlib import ticker

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.semilogy(df.set_index('a').b, 'o', markersize=2)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.3f'))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.3f'))

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]